# Model 'or TRUE' in Elasticsearch boolean query for nested type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build the following query in Elasticsearch:

```
(query1) AND (query2 OR query2 OR TRUE)
```

is the 'OR true' part possible using elasticsearch, or maybe there another way of structuring the query to give the same results?

I have a set of documents, say 10, all matching tag1, some of these 10 documents will also match tag2 and tag3 as well, and if so, I'm using named queries to tell me which documents match tag2 and tag3 (documents matching tag2 and tag3 are subsets of documents matching tag1).

However, even if none match tag2 or tag3, I should still get the results from the initial query matching tag1.

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "TAGS",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag1",
                  "_name": "tag1-query"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "TAGS.ID": {
                        "query": "tag2",
                        "_name": "tag2-query"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "TAGS.ID": {
                        "query": "tag3",
                        "_name": "tag3-query"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  // OR true here?
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Based on @Val's comment. Here is my full test:

```
PUT /test

PUT /test/_mapping/_doc 
{
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "TAGS": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }

}

POST /test/_doc
{
  "name" : "doc1",
  "TAGS" : [
    {
      "ID" : "tag1",
      "TYPE" : "BASIC"
    },
    {
      "ID" : "tag2",
      "TYPE" : "BASIC"
    }
  ]
}


# (tag1) and (tag2 or tag3 or true)
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "TAGS",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag1",
                  "_name": "tag1-query"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag2",
                  "_name": "tag2-query"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag3",
                  "_name": "tag3-query"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Running the above query only gives the following results:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.6931472,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SaOs8G4BbvPS27u-IouS",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc1",
          "TAGS" : [
            {
              "ID" : "tag1",
              "TYPE" : "BASIC"
            },
            {
              "ID" : "tag2",
              "TYPE" : "BASIC"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "TAGS" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 1,
              "max_score" : 0.6931472,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "test",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "SaOs8G4BbvPS27u-IouS",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "TAGS",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.6931472,
                  "_source" : {
                    "ID" : "tag1",
                    "TYPE" : "BASIC"
                  },
                  "matched_queries" : [
                    "tag1-query"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I.e. the `matched_queries` array only reported a match for `tag1-query`, when I would have expected it to contain `tag1-query` and `tag2-query`?

Comment: In that case you don't need `OR TRUE` because you'll get what you expect anyway ;-) You should simply move the `bool/should` out of the `must` and you're good to go. When using `must`, the `should` clauses are only useful for boosting the documents that match. Try it out!

Comment: Thanks @Val but if I moved the match queries out of the bool/should, would that not mean they are in the bool/must and so would be AND'd with the tag1 query?

Comment: No the `should` array should be sibling to the `must` array

Comment: Thanks @Val, tried that and still having problems, updated my answer with full reproduction steps, if you have time to look? :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two nested queries, because you're checking constraints on two different nested elements (which are two different nested documents under the hood). Try this out:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "TAGS",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "TAGS.ID": {
                "query": "tag1",
                "_name": "tag1-query"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "TAGS",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag2",
                  "_name": "tag2-query"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "TAGS",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag3",
                  "_name": "tag3-query"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val, the problem is the "inner_hits": {} now, I can only add it to one of the queries, otherwise, it complains, and it will only contain the matched_query for the query its added to. E.g. if I add it to the tag1 query, it correctly contains 'tag1-query', likewise, if I add it to the 'tag2-query', it correctly contains 'tag2-query'. It also compains when I try to add it to the very outermost query.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer since this is what I originally asked (how to model 'OR TRUE'), and I've raised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283035/using-matched-queries-for-nested-types-in-elasticsearch for the nested types issue I'm having, thanks @Val