# Using named queries (matched_queries) for nested types in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using named queries, I can get a list of the `matched_queries` for boolean expressions such as:

```
(query1) AND (query2 OR query3 OR true)
```

Here is an example of using named queries to match on top-level document fields:

```
DELETE test

PUT /test

PUT /test/_mapping/_doc 
{
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "TAGS": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }

}

POST /test/_doc
{
  "name" : "doc1",
  "type": "msword",
  "TAGS" : [
    {
      "ID" : "tag1",
      "TYPE" : "BASIC"
    },
    {
      "ID" : "tag2",
      "TYPE" : "BASIC"
    },
    {
      "ID" : "tag3",
      "TYPE" : "BASIC"
    }
  ]
}

# (query1) AND (query2 or query3 or true)
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "doc1",
              "_name": "query1"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": {
              "query": "msword",
              "_name": "query2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "type",
            "_name": "query3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query correctly returns all three `matched_queries` in the response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.5753641,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TKNJ9G4BbvPS27u-ZYux",
        "_score" : 1.5753641,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc1",
          "type" : "msword",
          "TAGS" : [
            {
              "ID" : "ds1",
              "TYPE" : "BASIC"
            },
            {
              "ID" : "wb1",
              "TYPE" : "BASIC"
            }
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "query1",
          "query2",
          "query3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I'm trying to run a similar search:

```
(query1) AND (query2 OR query3 OR true)
```

only this time on the nested TAGS object rather than top-level document fields.

I've tried the following query, but the problem is I need to supply the `inner_hits` object for nested objects in order to get the `matched_queries` in the response, and I can only add it to one of the three queries.

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "TAGS",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "TAGS.ID": {
                "query": "tag1",
                "_name": "tag1-query"
              }
            }
          },
          // "inner_hits" : {}
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "TAGS",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag2",
                  "_name": "tag2-query"
                }
              }
            },
            // "inner_hits" : {}
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "TAGS",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag3",
                  "_name": "tag3-query"
                }
              }
            },
            // "inner_hits" : {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch will complain if I add more than one 'inner_hits'. I've commented out the places above where I can add it, but each of these will only return the single matched query.

I want my response to this query to return:

```
 "matched_queries" : [
          "tag1-query",
          "tag2-query",
          "tag3-query"
        ]
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is a good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague helpfully provided a solution to this; move the `_named` parameter to directly under each `nested` section:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "_name": "tag1-query",
          "path": "TAGS",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "TAGS.ID": {
                "query": "tag1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "_name": "tag2-query",
            "path": "TAGS",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "_name": "tag3-query",
            "path": "TAGS",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "TAGS.ID": {
                  "query": "tag3"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This correctly returns all three tags now in the `matched_queries` response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 2.9424875,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TaNy9G4BbvPS27u--oto",
        "_score" : 2.9424875,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc1",
          "type" : "msword",
          "TAGS" : [
            {
              "ID" : "ds1",
              "TYPE" : "DATASOURCE"
            },
            {
              "ID" : "wb1",
              "TYPE" : "WORKBOOK"
            },
            {
              "ID" : "wb2",
              "TYPE" : "WORKBOOK"
            }
          ]
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "tag1-query",
          "tag2-query",
          "tag3-query"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is amazing! I was facing same issue and it helped me a lot!